# How to display the valueof a newly created custom model field in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have created a custom model in models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
#required by the auth model
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
NativeLanguage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
LearningLanguage = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

And also created an inline in admin.py, like this:

```
class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
model = UserProfile
can_delete = False
verbose_name_plural = 'UserProfile'

# Define a new User admin
class UserAdmin(BaseUserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )

# Re-register UserAdmin
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

I can give these two new fields values in the admin app, but when I try to call them in my html, I dont know how to reference them.

```
<p align="center">Native Language: {{????}}</p>
```

It must be something simple, but I cant seem to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, model field names should be lowercase underscore separated:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')
    native_language = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Later anywhere in the template or a view:

```
{{ user.profile.native_language }}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all html page renders from view.py
you have to send value of Native language from view to html page
in views native language is retrieved from models ..

In views.py ::

```
from .models import (model class name)  
data = model class name.objects.all().values('NativeLanguage')
return render(request, 'html page', {"data":data})
```

Something like this will render data from database to html page

then in html page

```
<p align="center">Native Language: {{data}}</p>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering. After defining the method in views and replacing model class name with my class, it is still not working.

Comment: sorry for this. but it will definitely work if makemigrations command is run after model changing then check by writing print after data retrieval like as print(data) if something is extracted or not then render the data to html page is not a big deal...

Comment: print data is not returning anything, but the field Native in my admin app is filled, I must be missing something really odd, but honestly im not getting it. I dont understand lol

Comment: have you tried \n data = UserProfile.objects.all().values('NativeLanguage')  then print data